# Will returning a const object from a function prevent move construction from outside?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Given this functions and function call:

```
std::string GetString() {
  std::stringstream sstr;
  const auto str = sstr.str();
  return str;
}

const auto returnedStr = GetString();
```

Will the move-construction be omitted as I declare `str` as const?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your case, `returnedStr` will be move-constructed from the return value of `GetString()`, but that return value will be copy-constructed from `str`<sup>(1)</sup>. If `str` wasn't `const`, the return value would be move-constructed from it.

Note that in both cases, return value optimisation is still applicable, so the compiler can still construct the return value (or even `str` itself) directly in the space of `returnedStr`, skipping one or both copy/move constructions. This is granted by C++11 12.8/31:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. In such cases,
>   the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different
>   ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of the times
>   when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization. This elision of copy/move
>   operations, called *copy elision,* is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to
>   eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>     non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified
>     type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>     the automatic object directly into the function’s return value
> - ...
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>     to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

The first bullet point covers the elision of the return value construction, the other one covers moving the return value into `returnedStr`. Notice the requirement on "the same cv-unqualified" type, which means that this works regardless of cv qualifiers.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that if we were talking about a class `X` other than `std::string`, one which provided a move constructor taking a `const X&&`, then indeed the return value would be move constructed using this constructor (whatever semantics it might have).

Comment: @PiotrS. Added, although I don't think the answer really needs one. It's just normal copy elision at work.

Comment: nice, but I didn't mean the requirements for ellision, rather the regular return

Comment: also, `X(const X&&);` is a *valid* move-constructor that will be invoked for above example if is declared, even if it is not sensible

Comment: *"A non-template constructor for class X is a move constructor if its first parameter is of type X&&, **const
X&&**, volatile X&&, or const volatile X&&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other
parameters have default arguments"*

Comment: @PiotrS. For the return, I see even less need for a standard quote. `std::string` does not declare a `std::string(const std::string &&)` ctor, so there is no way to move, period.

Comment: other types can, so returning const object does not prevent move construction for all types.

Comment: @PiotrS. OK, added. It is a generalisation of the OP's case, after all.

Comment: **+1**, the question is general imho, only the example is misleading/narrowing

Answer (score 8):

Angew's answer is right but who can remember all the language lawyer rules?

To help me remember it easier I wrote the following rules which came from STL's own mouth.

> 15. Don't return locals as const [16]

> $ Inhibits move semantics
>
> 16. Don't use move when returning local by value of
>     exact same type [16]

> $ NVRO won't be used if you do this.
>
> 17. Don't return by Rvalue reference (&&) [16]

> $ Unless you really really know what you're doing.

Notes:

[16] Don't Help the Compiler, Going Native 2013, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4

Comment: Thank you, thats how I like my answers :)